# Bad Request: query is too old and response timeout expired or query ID is invalid

Tags: python, telepot

I have been working a lot on a telegram bot for a long time now, but when I press an inline key to receive the pop up with:

```
bot.answerCallbackQuery (aalex_id, text = 'Notification at top of screen)
```

I get this error:

```
TelegramError: (u'Bad Request: query is too old and response timeout expired or query ID is invalid ', 400
```

the query id is just correct, and it's not that old lol...
I do not know what to do :c

Comment: tell me if something is lacking in the question :c

Comment: i have same problem when i checked the error logs, but everything working fine in my bot.

Answer (score 2):

You must use cache_time in answercallbackquery:
[See this link](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: This won't fix anything. The cache_time parameter is not a maximum wait time before the query expires. Instead, it specifies the amount of time, in seconds, that Telegram will keep the results cached on their server.

Answer (score 0):

i got this error when i used

```
["callback_query"]["message"]["message_id"]
```

instead of

```
['callback_query']['id']
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).